# businesscentralPrefix- Dynamic 365 Bussiness central

Tags: azure, dynamic, oauth-2.0, unauthorized

I'm Working Oauth2.0 authentication for Dynamic Bussiness central,
Actually i've Got all required tokens & the issue is i can't create any endpoints by using post, get , put, delete.
i dont know Why

[This is a document -- which is provide on official website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMvju.png)

[this is --  a bussiness central prefix mentioned in a hyperlink "guideline"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Gbf.png)

[Here the issue i faced , i gived a correct token ,plus i verified that already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO3ff.png)

[If did't give token, same issue was occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUPMQ.png)

So the issue is coming from  url

I don't know how to fix that :)